# Jmeter with CSV data: How to make a get post where Parameter is in the String not at the end

Tags: csv, jmeter, load

I'm using Jmeter for load testing done. I have successfully added a CSV data where i need to login with different users, that works fine, the CSV data is added to the end of the call.

Now I would like to make another call with CSV data, which contains a list of IDs. I need to make multiple GET calls with different IDs from that CSV file.

I have tried GET: api/Companies/${companyId}/random/request
Unfortunately this doesn't work cause it still adds the CSV data item at the end of the call instead of inside the string request.

How to I add a parameter from a CSV file into the Request String is my question?
I've tried {companyId} and ${companyId}

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `api/Companies/${companyId}/random/request` request should work fine

[image]

If it doesn't - check *jmeter.log* file, if JMeter cannot open the CSV file - you should see a message there. Also double check your CSV Data Set Config setup and ensure that the variable can be seen using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.

---

If you don't have too many IDs in the CSV file and it's the only column there you can consider using __StringFromFile() function instead of using the CSV Data Set Config like:

```
api/Companies/${__StringFromFile(test.csv)}/random/request
```

replace `test.csv` with the relative (or full) path to your CSV file

[image]

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to learn more about [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) concept, where and how they can be used, etc.